# What electronic component is this?

Tags: components, design

[image]

I am trying to build a spice simulation from a circuit diagram and came across this component. At first glance it looked like a FlipFlop to me, but I don't think that can be it.

So.... what is it?

Comment: Looks like a dual reset D-Type flip-flop or latch to me. But it could really be anything. Without some sort of reference it is  impossible to answer this. Where did you "come across" it?

Comment: Please include the circuit you got the symbol from

Answer (score 2):

The "D", "C", and "Q" pins suggest a "D input", "Clock input", and "Output" which is consistent with a D-type flip-flop. However, D flip-flops generally have two outputs - "Q" and "/Q" (NOT Q). Also, the R1 and R2 are confusing as I would have expected a "S" and "R" standing for "SET" and "RESET", respectively. Without seeing the actual circuit diagram from which this was taken it is very difficult, if not impossible, to give you a definitive answer.